# JS Error "Object expected" only on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error only on IE9 that the error says "SCRIPT5007: Object expected". There are 2 same error. One is at **$(document)** at beggining and another is marked as "<- error here"

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var imagePath = "/sites/all/modules/custom/sixdegrees_right_menu/images/";
            $(".menu-holder").mouseover(function()
            {
                //$(this).children(".menu-title").children(".menu-bg").hide();
                //$(this).children(".menu-title").children(".menu-name").css({"float":"none"});
                //$(this).children(".menu-title").children(".menu-text").css({"float":"none"});

                var imgSrc = $(this).children(".menu-icon").find("img").attr("src");
                imgSrc = imgSrc.replace(imagePath, "");
                imgSrc = imagePath + "h-" + imgSrc;
                $(this).children(".menu-icon").find("img").attr("src", imgSrc);
                <- error here
                //$(this).children(".menu-title").children(".menu-name").children("img").animate({"left": "0px"}, "slow");
                //$(this).children(".menu-title").children(".menu-text").animate({"left": "0px"}, "slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

There also have some commented lines which I don't have enough permission to delete it unless I can claim something.

Comment: can you post the related HTML?

Comment: use whatever instance of 'find and replace' you have in your IDE, search for $ and replace with jQuery. I'm just going to guess you probably have some MVC Framework or something installed.

Answer (score 2):

add a type="text/javascript" to your script tag, and make sure you are successfully including jQuery before attempting to use it.

Comment: +1 for the type. but if you don't include jQuery beforehand, the error would be something like "`$` not defined"

Comment: While the type attribute is required for valid HTML, in practice it isn't necessary (and hasn't been for a very long time) unless some other script language has already been used in the page. In any case, if jQuery hasn't been included then unless some other script has defined a value for `$` then an error will be thrown at the very first `$` and that will be that, it will never reach the "error here" line.

Comment: @Joseph—in IE the error is "Object expected" as reported by the OP.

Comment: both correct, just grasping at straws as i am not familiar with IE9's javascript interpreter :)

Comment: Some thing is magical here. I found this error at live server and also at our staging server. But at the evening it gone away from both server. I didn't change a bit of code.
See at live server - sixdegrees.org  on right side menu.